# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option when using CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting this error when I attempt to create tables.  This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE Club
    ( Club_ID          NUMBER(7)        NOT NULL
    , Club_Name        VARCHAR2(35)     NOT NULL
    , Street_Addr      VARCHAR2(40)     NOT NULL
    , City             VARCHAR2(20)     NOT NULL
    , State            CHAR(2)          NOT NULL
    , Zipcode          NUMBER(7)        NOT NULL
    , Phone            NUMBER(10)       NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT club_pk PRIMARY KEY (Club_ID)
    ) 

CREATE TABLE Member
    ( Member_ID        NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL
    , First_Name       VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL
    , Last_Name        VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL
    , Street_Addr      VARCHAR2(40)    NOT NULL
    , City             VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL
    , State            CHAR(2)         NOT NULL
    , Zipcode          NUMBER(7)       NOT NULL
    , Phone            NUMBER(10)      NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT member_pk PRIMARY KEY (Member_ID)
    ) ;
```

I don't get any errors from each individually, but as soon as I put them together like this I run into problems.  Adding a semicolon between the two CREATE TABLE sections causes a different error ("ORA-00911: invalid character"). What should I be doing differently?

Thanks!

Comment: separate your two statements with a `;`.

Comment: I'd recommend updating your question to explain that adding the semicolon doesn't help. I've deleted my answer so this will show up as unanswered again.

Comment: use `/` after each statement and remove the `;`s

Comment: What Oracle client are you running this from?

Comment: Using a / gets me the same result as using a ;

And I'm using APEX

Comment: APEX (the web interface) does not support running more than one statement. Use a real SQL client instead.

Comment: I'm doing this for a class and we're supposed to do it in APEX.  My instructor helped me write this in class and I saw his SQL briefly--it looked almost identical to mine.  I've asked him for help too, but he doesn't know what's wrong either.

Comment: Are you running that as a command or as a script?  They're different in ApEx.  A command is a single statement which can include SQL*Plus specific bits.  A script can have multiple statements, but only SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: As a script, you still need a / between statements.